# Lines disappeared when echo'd to file

Tags: string, batch-file

I'm trying to write a simple batch file that takes some characters from a file and writes them to another.
It must be simple but I've a problem: only the last line seems to be processed.

The source file `test001.txt` contains

```
 [
   "942877b2-c7f1e0ab-6c611041-66784a0b-a002493c",   
   "245af4a4-c514ffe4-6a71aae4-5555af5s-e5acb21a",   
   "186fe24f-5fa1ea17-2660e457-f955946a-e460d3bc",   
   "942877b2-c7f1e0ab-6c611041-66784a0b-a002493c",   
   "186fe24f-5fa1ea17-2660e457-f955946a-e460d3bc" 
 ]
```

The number of lines may vary but the structure is the same.
Now I'm using this code

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion
set "infile=test001.txt"
if not exist %infile% (
    echo File '%infile%' does not exist^^!
    goto :eof
)
for /f tokens^=2^ delims^=^" %%F in (%infile%) do (
     echo %%F
)
```

and I get the desidered output, that is:

```
942877b2-c7f1e0ab-6c611041-66784a0b-a002493c
245af4a4-c514ffe4-6a71aae4-5555af5s-e5acb21a
186fe24f-5fa1ea17-2660e457-f955946a-e460d3bc
942877b2-c7f1e0ab-6c611041-66784a0b-a002493c
186fe24f-5fa1ea17-2660e457-f955946a-e460d3bc
```

If I redirect the output to a file adding `>fileout.txt` after `echo %%F`, the file `fileout.txt` contains only the last line.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Change it to ```(for /f usebackq^ tokens^=2^ delims^=^" %%F in ("%infile%") do echo %%F) >"fileout.txt"```. Alternatively ```for /f usebackq^ tokens^=2^ delims^=^" %%F in ("%infile%") do >>"fileout.txt" echo %%F```. Then change ```if not exist %infile% (``` to ```if not exist "%infile%" (``` as well. You can also remove the option for delaying variable expansion and the escaping carets for the exclamation mark.

Comment: `>` is "(over)write", `>>?` is "append". Either change your `>` to `>>` or - better and much faster - use Compo`s suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an extension of my comment, *(with an additional example)*.

Preferred single write method, *(from comment)*:

```bash
@Echo Off
Setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

Set "infile=test001.txt"

If Not Exist "%infile%"" (Echo File '%infile%' does not exist!
    %SystemRoot%\System32\timeout.exe /T 5 /NoBreak 1>NUL & GoTo :EOF)

(   For /F UseBackQ^ Tokens^=2^ Delims^=^" %%G In ("%infile%") Do Echo %%G
) 1>"FileOut.txt"
```

Append alternative 1:

```bash
@Echo Off
Setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

Set "infile=test001.txt"

If Not Exist "%infile%"" (Echo File '%infile%' does not exist!
    %SystemRoot%\System32\timeout.exe /T 5 /NoBreak 1>NUL & GoTo :EOF)

For /F UseBackQ^ Tokens^=2^ Delims^=^" %%G In ("%infile%"
) Do (Echo %%G) 1>>"FileOut.txt"
```

Append alternative 2, *(from comment)*:

```bash
@Echo Off
Setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

Set "infile=test001.txt"

If Not Exist "%infile%"" (Echo File '%infile%' does not exist!
    %SystemRoot%\System32\timeout.exe /T 5 /NoBreak 1>NUL & GoTo :EOF)

For /F UseBackQ^ Tokens^=2^ Delims^=^" %%G In ("%infile%"
) Do 1>>"FileOut.txt" Echo %%G
```